# How do I change the locale that JasperReports uses?

Tags: jasper-reports, locale

The windows installed on my machine has the locale `en_AU` and that's what JasperReports uses. I already tried changing the locale of all users, including the Administrator but it still uses `en_AU`.

How can I change that locale? Is it possible to change the `REPORT_LOCALE` parameter on my report?

Answer (score 62):

The locale is set during execution, not in the JRXML.

Using Java, set the `REPORT_LOCALE` parameter for the report's parameter map. For example:

```
InputStream reportTemplate = getReportTemplate();
JRDataSource dataSource = getDataSource();

java.util.Map parameters = getParameters();
java.util.Locale locale = new Locale( "en", "US" );
parameters.put( JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale );

JasperFillManager.fillReport( reportTemplate, parameters, dataSource );
```

Using Jaspersoft Studio, open the project properties dialog to the **Report Execution** area:

[image: Project Properties]

Using iReport, set the report locale in the Options window under the "Report execution options" section in the General tab. This will set the report locale when run.

Comment: The "report execution options" have moved to: Options -> iReport -> Compilation and execution -> Execution options

Answer (score 0):

You can set the locale on JVM that executes the `JasperFillManager` code if you do not want to change the code:

```
java -Duser.language=de -Duser.country=CH ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set the locale `net.sf.jasperreports.default.locale` property in the `jasperreports.properties` file.